# Validating FHIR profiles

Tags: dstu2-fhir, hapi-fhir, hl7-fhir

I'm wondering if there is a way to validate FHIR profiles?

By this I mean validate the xml definition of my profile/extensions are valid, not validate a resource against my profile.

I'm asking this because I've build a tool for producing profiles, and I need to test that the output is correct (and I can't find a definitive clear document that states what is right and wrong).

I'm using HAPI if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to use the implementation guide publisher. See http://wiki.hl7.org/index.php?title=IG_Publisher_Documentation#Command_Line_Mode - look for the alternative mode

Comment: Any idea where you get hold of igpublisher.jar?  The documentation links to the download page: http://hl7.org/fhir/downloads.html, but it doesn't appear to be listed as a download.

Comment: You need to get the IGPublisher from the current build at build.fhir.org

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can upload your StructureDefinition to [Simplifier.net](https://simplifier.net/), which will do basic validation of the StructureDefinition. When it renders correctly on the Simplifier site after uploading, you'll know you're SD is valid.

Comment: Would you not validate the structure definition against incoming resources on the server?

Comment: @ThomasJohansen rather the other way around. If you have a specific SD on your server, you can/will validate incoming resources against that. But the question was how to validate your profile (=SD). Of course, if your server has basic validation, you can validate the SD on your server as well.